# Show that $\lim_{a\rightarrow0+}a^{p}\omega(a)=0$ whenever $f\in L^{p}(E)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Show that $\lim_{a\rightarrow0+}a^{p}\omega(a)=0$ whenever $f\in L^{p}(E)$
,where $p\in(0,\infty)$ and $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ it can be finite measure or not and $\omega(\alpha)=\bigg|\{x\in E :f(x)>\alpha\}\bigg|$

Here is my edited proof :

As $f\in L^{p}(E)$ we have $|f|\in L^{p}$ and $|f|$ is non-negative on $E$, then one has the following formula :
$$\bigg\lVert |f|\bigg\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^{p}=p\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{p-1}\omega(\alpha)\,d\alpha<+\infty$$

So,for each $a>0$

\begin{align}
0\leq a^p\omega(a)=p\int_{0}^{a}t^{p-1}\omega(a)\,dt\leq p\int_{0}^{a}t^{p-1}\omega(t)\,dt
\end{align}

Then as $a\longrightarrow0+$,one has $$p\int_{0}^{a}t^{p-1}\omega(t)\,dt\longrightarrow0$$
,since $$p\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{p-1}\omega(\alpha)\,d\alpha<+\infty$$

Whence,our result follows.

Is there any problem about my working ? Any suggestions and remind would be appreciated.Thank you for the time to check my proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first line does not hold: The contra-proposition of negative a.e. is not positive a.e.

Rather, you don't have to consider the positiveness of $f$, because we have the nice formula that

\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{L^{p}}^{p}=p\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{p-1}\omega(t)dt<\infty.
\end{align*}
Note that 
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{L^{p}}^{p}=\int_{E}|f|^{p}d\mu=\big\||f|\big\|_{L^{p}}^{p},
\end{align*}
the positiveness of $f$ does not play any role in the proof. And the way to derive the nice formula, the positiveness of the function is not taken into account.